# Problem loading java properties

Tags: java, file, properties

I am trying to load properties from a file (test.properties)

The code I use is as follows:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("../resources/test.properties");
properties.load(url.openStream());
```

But when executing the second line I get a NPE. (null pointer exception)

I'm not sure what's wrong here... I have checked that the file exists at the location where URL points to...

Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it perhaps the `properties` object that is `null`?

Comment: This was the problem.. I just forgot to instantiate the properties object... And was so confident that there was something wrong with the loading of the file... Thanks for help...

Comment: @markovuksanovic: you're welcome... we've all wasted time looking for a complex solution to a simple problem one time or another.

Answer (score 3):

The javadoc for [`Class.getResource(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) says:

> Returns:  a URL object **or null** if no resource with this name is found

Most likely, the problem is that getResource is not finding the resource it is looking for.  I am very suspicious of the use of `".."` in the resource name.  The javadoc does not say that `getResource` treats `"."` or `".."` path components as having special meaning.

It is also possible that `properties` is null ...

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but I don't *believe* you can use ".." like that in a call to `getResource()`. I suggest you try an "absolute" resource:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/path/to/resources/test.properties");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to whether or not `getResource` will find your file depends on your system classloader.  The classloader is called, but before the classloader is called, the following transformation is made on the string you pass in.

From the Class javadoc:

> - If the name begins with a '/'  ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of 
>     the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>   modified_package_name/name
>
>   Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object 
>     with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

So, the question becomes: will the classloader you are using be able to resolve `modified_package_name/../resources/test.properties`?

Answer (score 0):

`getClass().getResource()` resolves the resource relative to the given class. Try `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Apache's [PropertiesConfiguration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html)